# download link for latest Rhino mocks binaries (googling didn't help)

Tags: rhino-mocks

can someone share the link to download the latest version of Rhino mocks binaries (binaries only, I don't need source)? the link http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks/downloads.aspx, doesn't seem to work anymore. it gets redirected to the blog. I have tried another link mentioned in the blog https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-mocks, but I can't find a link in there to download just the binaries alone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems to be the daily build repository fwiw.

http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/Rhino-Mocks

Comment: Thanks for the link, a bit surprised there isn't a proper link for download, instead I have to pick one from the daily builds.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the new official link (as of today, according to ayende): http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks

Comment: on which the download link is http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/Rhino-Mocks ... from there, select a build

Comment: I wouldn't download it from there. Take a look at the license agreement. Extremely proprietary sounding. But, the git repo is BSD licensed heh

Comment: Rhino Mocks is indeed open source (BSD) - the proprietary license page has since been removed.  See: http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks.  I emailed support at Rhino, and Oren responded personally saying that the page could be ignored (and it's since been removed)

Answer (score 5):

You can also [download latest Rhino Mocks binaries from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/rhinomocks).